# Updating an internal SQLite Database after the app has been published

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am very fairly novice to AndroidStudio and want to create a project of my own.
My question is:

1. Can you update a Database outside of republishing your app?

   - Say I have published the app and the Database is currently empty. Then later I want to add some data  How would I add this data to the DB without having to change fundamental source code, or redevelop the app? I am using SQLite.

I would like to publish this application as a Network app. That is I want all users to view the same information from "empty" Database and whatever is populated. Could you guys give me a direction or a minimally functional example of Network apps / their requirements. I have never used or developed them before.

END_RESULT:

- Users should download an app (this app) and be able to be able to collect news added to its feed.

  - The maintenance crew, should be able to add/populate the app via a database reasonably without having to redeploy the app every time new material is added.

Comment: You could have your app download the latest SQLite database from your server on startup.

Comment: Scratch that, I've used network apps, Snapchat, Social Media apps, etc. But I have never developed any lol -- Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to implement some kind of server backend that your app communicates to in order to download new data. The app must already have logic for how to process that data and store it locally in SQLite, but that can be fairly straightforward. As for how to sync or download new data, there are several possibilities.

1. Perform a sync when the app starts. You may or may not want to do this if you are using some other (periodic) mechanism.
2. Schedule periodic syncs with JobScheduler. This is a good practice in that JobScheduler doesn't have to run your task at a specific time, it can run it within a certain time window so that your task coincides with other apps that need to run tasks. Since your task would spin up the radio and make network requests, the system can let other apps that need the radio also run at the same time to reduce the number of radio wakeups (and thus be more battery efficient).
3. Implement Google Cloud Messaging so that your backend can send a push notification to your app, and your app can receive this as a signal to perform a sync.

Note you aren't limited to only one of these.

Comment: This sounds not only difficult, lol, but fun and on first look sounds //efficient. I will also look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, if you add **Realtime Database**.

This is a database hosted on a server instead of directly on the phone, which can push informations to clients to synchronize new data on them.

Otherwise, you need to update the app to get new content.

One wonderful tool to achieve this is Firebase.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad ended question and as such difficult to provide specific answer to. What do you mean by 'updating a database outside of republishing your app' ?

1. Do you mean update the database schema  - YES, it can be done.
2. Put data into database - Yes, the app owning the database can do it anytime based on it's business logic.Which means the source code to insert the data should already be embedded into your published app. Only thing that should be decided on the fly, is when to execute this code.
   Normally for a networked app, it's a norm to refresh the data when the app is launched. This means you can put a network call in your app's main screen launch and download whatever you wanted to download and put it into database. Your maintenance crew can put the data on a server and let the app download it.
3. Android has a plethora of network libraries and the choice depends on what kind of content you are downloading. Will suggest to try out Volley (Official from Google) and Retrofit (If you want something slicker)